Google OAuth with an Azure AppSerivice behind front door
We have an AppService that's running on linux that serves a Web application.We need to reactivate the google Single Sign on that stopped working from when we moved the application from a virtual machine to Azure AppService.
The issue we got is that I don't know how to configure the name sent to the google API in order to avoid an URL mismatch.
What I got when I try to login is
Errore 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Richiedi dettagli: redirect_uri=https://wa-ecomXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/account/signin-google flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow 

I've also tried to pass the FD domain alias but nothing... anyone faced this in the past the same issue? What should I put in the console of google? the internal Azure name or the FD one?
Thanks
